# Избегание дублирования выводимых сообщений логгера в модуле logging

Tags: python, логирование

Возникла следующая проблема. Для логирования использую модуль logging. Есть 2 скрипта: один бесконечный цикл, который в процессе работы вызывает функцию из другого скрипта. В вызываемом скрипте создается логгер (вывод в определенный файл, в определенном формате и тд и тп). Логгеры получаются по имени

```
logger = logging.getLogger(f'{function.__name__}')
```

т.е. каждый раз получаю один и тот же логгер. после чего вывожу в файл лога сообщения. Проблема в том, что сообщение дублируется для каждой ссылки на логгер, то есть при первом вызове функции сообщение печатается 1 раз, при втором - 2 раза и так далее. Думал перед выходом из функции как то отключать экземпляр, типа

```
logger.disabled = True
```

но не сработало, подскажите как сделать, чтобы сообщения не дублировались для каждой новой ссылке на логгер

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Проблема была в функции настройки логера, я каждый раз при заходе в функцию получал логер, и закидывал его в функцию настройки, где ему задавался хендлер (в какой файл, в каком виде выводить) и получается каждый раз в список обработчиков добавлялся новый обработчик с теми же настройками, и логгер выводил сообщение в файл на каждый обработчик